# Tutorial of ECDSA algorithm to sign a string

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

Can you help me to find a simple tutorial of how sign a string using ECDSA algorithm in java. But without using any third-party libraries like bouncycastle. Just JDK 7. I found it difficult to search a simple example, I'm new to cryptography.

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;

public class GenSig {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Generate a DSA signature
         */

        try {

            /*
             * Generate a key pair
             */

            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");

            keyGen.initialize(1024, random);

            KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate();
            PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();

            /*
             * Create a Signature object and initialize it with the private key
             */

            Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");

            dsa.initSign(priv);

            String str = "This is string to sign";
            byte[] strByte = str.getBytes();
            dsa.update(strByte);

            /*
             * Now that all the data to be signed has been read in, generate a
             * signature for it
             */

            byte[] realSig = dsa.sign();
            System.out.println("Signature: " + new String(realSig));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught exception " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

How to modify it for ECDSA?

Comment: Look for any example that uses DSA, but use these algorithms instead: [EC provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC)

Comment: for example if I use this tutorial, what should I change here? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/Testthesignature.htm     or using this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step1.html    should I place instead of dsa ecdsa?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is small example based on your example.

**NOTE:** this is the original code for this answer, please see the next code snippet for an updated version.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;

public class ECDSAExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Generate an ECDSA signature
         */

        /*
         * Generate a key pair
         */

        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

        keyGen.initialize(256, random);

        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();

        /*
         * Create a Signature object and initialize it with the private key
         */

        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA");

        dsa.initSign(priv);

        String str = "This is string to sign";
        byte[] strByte = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        dsa.update(strByte);

        /*
         * Now that all the data to be signed has been read in, generate a
         * signature for it
         */

        byte[] realSig = dsa.sign();
        System.out.println("Signature: " + new BigInteger(1, realSig).toString(16));

    }
}
```

UPDATE: Here is slightly improved example removing deprecated algorithms. It also explicitly requests the NIST P-256 curve using the SECG notation "secp256r1" as specified in [RFC 8422.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8422)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;

public class ECDSAExample {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Generate an ECDSA signature
         */

        /*
         * Generate a key pair
         */

        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");

        keyGen.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"), new SecureRandom());

        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();

        /*
         * Create a Signature object and initialize it with the private key
         */

        Signature ecdsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");

        ecdsa.initSign(priv);

        String str = "This is string to sign";
        byte[] strByte = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        ecdsa.update(strByte);

        /*
         * Now that all the data to be signed has been read in, generate a
         * signature for it
         */

        byte[] realSig = ecdsa.sign();
        System.out.println("Signature: " + new BigInteger(1, realSig).toString(16));

    }
}
```

Comment: What curve would that be? P-256?

Comment: I was afraid someone would ask that. I don't know, P-256 would be my guess though.

Comment: Running it in the debugger and cheating a little reveals: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1]

Comment: Oh, I just cast it to the ECPrivateKey and got the curve :) I like to explicitly name the curve though.

Comment: thanks a lot for analysis. I will try and write a bit later=)

Comment: @GregS you know the dangers of calling String.getBytes() without an explicit character set...

Comment: @Jumbogram I just did a copy and paste of the OPs example and missed it. Fixed now.

Comment: Does it support SHA-256 too? The security margin of SHA-1 against collisions is a bit on the low side, so I'd recommend SHA-256 where possible. P256 on the other hand is a fine curve, so no complaints about that part.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It does. I didn't actually verify the signatures, but the example runs if you use instead `Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");` or any of the SHA2 algorithms in place of SHA256.

Comment: I do want to thank you for this answer. I have been banging my head on a problem for the past several hours with using ECDSA and then the keystore camplaining that the algorithms dont match...Now it works, just wanted to share my gratitude.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes
`System.err.println("Public Key: " + pub.toString()); `

shows

Public Key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 19501778814434347530334294264752414149486648444804770040426369360038920483177
  public y coord: 114925210518466507390625110183293395999411704799479237295270124024949219180290
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)

Answer (score 7):

```
class ECCCipher {
    @Override
    public byte[] sign(PrivateKey privateKey, String message) throws Exception {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);

        signature.update(message.getBytes());

        return signature.sign();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verify(PublicKey publicKey, byte[] signed, String message) throws Exception {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA");
        signature.initVerify(publicKey);

        signature.update(message.getBytes());

        return signature.verify(signed);
    }
}
```

========================

```
public class ECCCipherTest {

private final KeyPairGenerator keygen;

public ECCCipherTest() throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    this.keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    keygen.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("brainpoolP384r1"));
}

@Test
public void ECC_CipherTest_1() throws Exception {
    String message = "hello world";

    ICipher<PrivateKey, PublicKey> cipher = new ECCCipher();
    KeyPair keyPair = keygen.generateKeyPair();

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.sign(keyPair.getPrivate(), message);

    Assert.assertTrue(cipher.verify(keyPair.getPublic(), encrypted, message));
}
```

}

this is a small code snippet from my project.
it works for me. I have included one junit test as well;
hopefully this helps.

just in case anyone wonders how we load the private key and pubkey:
(note: privKey is the byte array representing the BigInteger in java, and the pubKey is the curve point in binary format)

```
    @Override
public PrivateKey generatePrivateKey(byte[] keyBin) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("secp256k1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
    ECPrivateKeySpec privKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(keyBin), params);
    return kf.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
}

@Override
public PublicKey generatePublicKey(byte[] keyBin) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("secp256k1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
    ECPoint point =  ECPointUtil.decodePoint(params.getCurve(), keyBin);
    ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, params);
    return kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
}
```

Comment: What is `ECCCipher`?

Comment: @VladMarkushin it's just a class I named, ECC : Elliptic Curve Cryptography.

Comment: @VladMarkushin oh it's actually the first block of the code. ok I added the class name there, so now you can see.